# Flash Builder 4.5 strange formatting

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, formatting, flash-builder, flexbuilder

My Flash Builder 4.5 code formatting behaves strangely.

Whenever I start the new line without closing previous one with the semicolon (`;`), it idents the next line by one tab.

How can i fix that? Seems like it's code formatter relies on semicolons, but that's ridiculous: not everyone puts them in the end of the line :(

(BTW, FDT doesn't rely on semicolons on code formatting)

**Update**: installed FB 4.6 - same problem. Maybe there are some plugins that will fix that? I don't want to pay $600 for FDT :)

**Update2**: here's the video showing the problem: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b4oZvRJk_ps&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I believe that was to encourage the "good" practice of ending lines with semicolons to match C-based languages. Formatting the code later should remove the offending indent.

Comment: Well, every time I press return it adds a new tab, so write 150 lines of code - and you are offscreen :) It formats code like it's a stairs. And formatting code later does not help (even if it could help - it's not like it's a solution :) .

Comment: Isn't it simpler to add semicolons after each line? :)

Comment: Well, I switch betwenn python and as3 all the time, it's sometimes really confusing to start typing curly braces in python after debugging a flash project, so if I start using semicolons in as3, I think my brain will go crazy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to fix that. The only possible solution is to disable automatic indenting - at least it's nicer that way.

Answer (score 1):

FlexPrettyPrint (http://sourceforge.net/projects/flexformatter/) is a plugin I use. You can configure it to format the file on save, and manually when needed. See (http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/flexformatter/index.php?title=Preferences#FlexFormatter_AutoFormat)

Comment: nope. you need to format the code. I think that's the only option you've got. Flash Builder relies on semicolons for indenting, it seems. I've assigned a shortcut key (Ctrl+Shift+F twice) to invoke the formatter

Comment: Thx, but that's not a solution to me. Seems, like i got to buy FDT :( since there a lot more uncomfortable things in FB

Comment: Flash Developer Tool by Powerflasher. The only comfortable IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the toolbar under `Window > Preferences`

Then `Flex Formatting`

Under the `Newlines/wrapping` tab there is a section on Line breaks.

Could have a play with the options here?

[image: Flex Formatting Screenshot]

Comment: Can't find it in Flash Builder 4.5

Comment: Which bit can't you find? Are you running Windows or Mac?

Comment: There is no Flex Formatting or any other Formatting option for as3 in Flash Builder, only a couple Identation options. Im running FB on Mac, but that does not really matter, since FB is written in Java :)

Comment: Are you sure you are not using any plugin?

Comment: Apologies, it's been such a long time since I set up my IDE. It turns out I am using a plugin. It's FlexPrettyPrintCommand: http://sourceforge.net/projects/flexformatter/